# ¿Cómo proteger los intercambios de variables con un mutex por posición del array?

Tags: c, hilos

Resulta que tengo un código que permite intercambiar los valores de un
array que se comparte entre varios threads. Cada thread ejecuta un bucle donde escoge dos posiciones de forma aleatoria e intercambia los valores que hay en ellas.

Me piden que modifique el código propuesto para que el código sea más eficiente y el enunciado es este:

En  el  ejercicio  anterior  añadimos  un  mutex  para  controlar  los  accesos  concurrentes  al array. El programa funciona correctamente, pero al haber un solo mutex cada vez que un thread quiere hacer un intercambio tiene que bloquear el acceso a todo el array, aunque podamos tener threads que vayan a intercambiar posiciones distintas. Para ganar en eficiencia vamos a proteger cada posición con un mutex. Para hacer el intercambio de dos variables tendremos, por tanto, que bloquear los dos mutex correspondientes a esas variables.
Tenga en cuenta que en este apartado es necesario bloquear dos mutex para hacer cada intercambio, y que esto puede provocar interbloqueos. Aplique alguna de las técnicas de interbloque para evitarlo. Compruebe con el comando *time* que el programa ejecuta los intercambios en un tiempo menor
que con un solo mutex.

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "options.h"

pthread_mutex_t swap_mutex;  //Ejercicio 1

struct buffer {
    int *data;
    int size;
};

struct thread_info {
    pthread_t       thread_id;        // id returned by pthread_create()
    int             thread_num;       // application defined thread #
};

struct args {
    int         thread_num;       // application defined thread #
    int              delay;       // delay between operations
    int         iterations;
    struct buffer  *buffer;       // Shared buffer
};

void *swap(void *ptr)
{
    struct args *args =  ptr;
    int tmpsum;
    while(args->iterations--) {
        int i,j, tmp;

        i=rand() % args->buffer->size;
        j=rand() % args->buffer->size;

        printf("Thread %d swapping positions %d(%d) and %d(%d)\n", 
             args->thread_num, i, args->buffer->data[i], j, args->buffer->data[j]);

        //pthread_mutex_lock(&swap_mutex); //Ejercicio 1

        tmp = args->buffer->data[i];
        printf("Thread %d tmp positions %d \n", args->thread_num, tmp);
        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay); // Force a context switch

        args->buffer->data[i] = args->buffer->data[j];
        printf("Thread %d i<-j positions %d(%d) and %d(%d)\n", 
             args->thread_num, i, args->buffer->data[i], j,
             args->buffer->data[j]);        
        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay);

        args->buffer->data[j] = tmp;
        printf("Thread %d j<-tmp positions %d(%d) and %d\n", 
           args->thread_num, j, args->buffer->data[j], tmp);
        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay);

        printf("Thread %d buffer ", args->thread_num);
        tmpsum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < args->buffer->size; i++){
            tmpsum = args->buffer->data[i] + tmpsum;
            printf("%i ", args->buffer->data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n%i\n",tmpsum);

        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay);

        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&swap_mutex); //Ejercicio 1
    }
    return NULL;
}

void print_buffer(struct buffer buffer) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < buffer.size; i++)
        printf("%i ", buffer.data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

 void start_threads(struct options opt)
{
    int i;
    struct thread_info *threads;
    struct args *args;
    struct buffer buffer;

    srand(time(NULL));

    if((buffer.data=malloc(opt.buffer_size*sizeof(int)))==NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    buffer.size = opt.buffer_size;

    for(i=0; i<buffer.size; i++)
        buffer.data[i]=i;

    printf("creating %d threads\n", opt.num_threads);
    threads = malloc(sizeof(struct thread_info) * opt.num_threads);
    args = malloc(sizeof(struct args) * opt.num_threads);

    if (threads == NULL || args==NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Buffer before: ");
    print_buffer(buffer);


    // Create num_thread threads running swap() 
    for (i = 0; i < opt.num_threads; i++) {
        threads[i].thread_num = i;

        args[i].thread_num = i;
        args[i].buffer     = &buffer;
        args[i].delay      = opt.delay;
        args[i].iterations = opt.iterations;

        if ( 0 != pthread_create(&threads[i].thread_id, NULL,
                     swap, &args[i])) {
             printf("Could not create thread #%d", i);
             exit(1);
        }
    }

     // Wait for the threads to finish
     for (i = 0; i < opt.num_threads; i++)
         pthread_join(threads[i].thread_id, NULL);

    // Print the buffer
    printf("Buffer after:  ");
    print_buffer(buffer);
    free(args);
    free(threads);
    free(buffer.data);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct options opt;

    // Default values for the options
    opt.num_threads = 10;
    opt.buffer_size = 10;
    opt.iterations  = 100;
    opt.delay       = 10;

    read_options(argc, argv, &opt);

    start_threads(opt);

    exit (0);
}
```

La que hay que modificar es la función *swap*. Podéis ver entre comentarios el mutex_lock y unlock que era lo que pedía el primer ejercicio. Pero en este segundo debo hacer como dice en el enunciado. Yo he intentado resolverlo por mi cuenta pero de momento no he sido posible, ya que no encuentro la forma de hacer que no se repitan valores en los intercambios y además bajar el tiempo de ejecución del código, que es lo que hay que hacer. Os agradecería mucho si me pudierais ayudar a dar con la solución.

Muchas gracias

Actualización:

Os muestro cómo tengo el código ahora mismo, estoy utilizando un pthread_mutex_t mutex[10]. Adjunto la función swap en la que lo uso el array. El resto del código del programa no lo he modificado.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex[10];

void *swap(void *ptr)
{
    struct args *args =  ptr;
    int tmpsum;
    while(args->iterations--) {
         int i, j, tmp;

         i=rand() % args->buffer->size;
         j=rand() % args->buffer->size;

         printf("Thread %d swapping positions %d(%d) and %d(%d)\n", 
            args->thread_num, i, args->buffer->data[i], j, args->buffer->data[j]);

         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[i]);
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[j]);

         tmp = args->buffer->data[i];
         printf("Thread %d tmp positions %d \n", args->thread_num, tmp);
         if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay); // Force a context switch

         args->buffer->data[i] = args->buffer->data[j];
         printf("Thread %d i<-j positions %d(%d) and %d(%d)\n", 
                 args->thread_num, i, args->buffer->data[i], j,
                 args->buffer->data[j]);        
        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay);

        args->buffer->data[j] = tmp;
        printf("Thread %d j<-tmp positions %d(%d) and %d\n", 
                args->thread_num, j, args->buffer->data[j], tmp);
        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay);

        printf("Thread %d buffer ", args->thread_num);
        tmpsum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < args->buffer->size; i++){
             tmpsum = args->buffer->data[i] + tmpsum;
             printf("%i ", args->buffer->data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n%i\n",tmpsum);
        if(args->delay) usleep(args->delay);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[i]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[j]);        
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Si te respondemos te hacemos el ejercicio al completo... ¿no has intentado nada? ¿no se te ha ocurrido ninguna posible solución?

Comment: He intentado bastantes cosas. Ahora mismo estoy usando un pthread_mutex_t mutex[10]  para que bloquee las posiciones dadas por i y j y asi el siguiente thread tenga que coger otras posiciones, asi cada thread coge dos posiciones distintas y no habria problema en el intercambio, pero me falta algo porque a la mitad de la ejecución se me para.

Comment: Se te para porque tienes un abrazo mortal... imagínate que tienes dos hilos y el primero bloquea el índice 3, después el segundo hilo bloquea el índice 4, después el primer hilo intenta bloquear el índice 4 (no puede y se queda esperando) y finalmente el segundo hilo intenta bloquear el 3 (no puede y se queda esperando)... eso es un abrazo mortal... si no pones el código que llevas puesto es complicado que tengas respuestas.

Comment: El código que he adjuntado arriba, es como lo tengo ahora mismo

Answer (score 1):

Como bien has comentado:

> pero me falta algo porque a la mitad de la ejecución se me para.

el problema se llama "abrazo mortal" y esto se produce así:

- El hilo 1 bloquea A
- El hilo 2 bloquea B
- El hilo 1 intenta bloquear B (no puede y se queda esperando)
- El hilo 2 intenta bloquear A (no puede y se queda esperando)
- El hilo 3 intenta bloquear A o B (no puede y se queda esperando)
- Repite el paso anterior con el resto de hilos

En estos casos no tienes que llamar a `pthread_mutex_lock()` sino a [`pthread_mutex_trylock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) y verificar que has podido bloquear los dos *mutex*. Si uno de los dos falla tienes que elegir cómo actuar:

- Desbloqueas el *mutex* bloqueado y abortas la iteración actual (no el hilo)
- Solicitas un nuevo índice e intentas bloquearlo... si no lo consigues vuelves a intentarlo (hasta que consigas bloquear uno).

Tu código corregido quedaría así:

```
int mutex1 = pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex[i]);
int mutex2 = pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex[j]);

if( mutex1 == 0 && mutex2 == 0 )
{
  // Los dos mutex bloqueados
}
else
{
  // Al menos uno de los dos mutex ya esta bloqueado por otro hilo
}
```